# Как применить метод clone() класса Object?

Tags: java, объекты, клонирование

Код, написанный мной для тренировки:

```
class Korobka {

    public double width, depth, height; //Объявление переменных
    public static int id = 4;

    Korobka(double w, double d, double h) {
        width = w;
        depth = d;
        height = h;
    }

    double volume() {
        return width * depth * height;
    }

    void measurement() {
        System.out.println("Длина коробки " + width);
        System.out.println("Ширина коробки " + depth);
        System.out.println("Высота коробки " + height);
        System.out.println("Объем коробки " + volume());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Korobka k1 = new Korobka(4.5, 3.6, 3.7);
        Korobka k2 = new Korobka(4, 5, 6);
        k1.measurement();
        k2.measurement();
        int ID = Korobka.id;
        System.out.println(ID);
    }
}
```

Вздумалось мне метод `clone()` из класса `Object` применить.

Вопросы:

1. Могу ли я применить этот метод, к примеру, к коробке `k1` (для клонирования)?
2. Если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: Рекомендую прочитать Joshua Bloch - Effective Java.

Comment: @NickVolynkin только что читал главу про клонирование. Не помогло.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В дополнение к предыдущим ответам хочу отметить, что лучше реализовать `clone()` вот так:

```
class Korobka implements Cloneable {
  @Override
  public Korobka clone() {
    try {
      return (Korobka)super.clone();
    }
    catch( CloneNotSupportedException ex ) {
      throw new InternalError();
    }
  }    
  //всё остальное
}
```

Так как вы интерфейс `Cloneable` указали, `CloneNotSupportedException` никогда случиться не должен, и пользователи вашего класса не должны мучаться с ним, оборачивая вызовы в try-catch. Кроме того вы можете быть уверены, что возвращаемый объект имеет тип `Korobka` и привести тип сами. Тогда пользователи смогут просто писать:

```
Korobka copy = k1.clone();
```

Вообще у клонирования много проблем и оно не всегда хорошо (хотя бывают случаи, когда очень удобно). Альтернативой клонированию служит конструктор копирования:

```
class Korobka {
  Korobka(double w, double d, double h) {
    width = w;
    depth = d;
    height = h;
  }

  Korobka(Korobka other) {
    this(other.width, other.depth, other.height);
  }
}
```

Пользоваться тогда немного по-другому:

```
Korobka copy = new Korobka(k1);
```

Comment: а можетe ещё опционально ответите, почему при коде:
     Korobka copy = k1.clone();
Выражение типа:            
     if(copy.equals(k1)){
            System.out.println(true);
         }else {
            System.out.println(false);
          }

Даёт  **False**.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, потому что надо ещё метод `equals()` переопределить. По умолчанию он не сравнивает содержимое объекта, а возвращает `true`, только если это один и тот же объект. В Effective Java и про `equals` должно быть, поищите.

Answer (score 2):

Да сможете. В java объекты передаются по ссылкам. Т.е. следующий код

```
    Object o1 = new Object();
    Object o2 = o1;
```

создаёт один объект, на который указывают две ссылки. Очень часто это бывает не удобно - изменяем объект о1 изменяется объект о2. А, к примеру, нужно было в объект о2 просто скопировать значения из о1, но никак не связывать их.

Для этих целей был введён интерфейс Cloneable.
В своём клаccе вам нужно реализовать его:

```
    class Korobka implements Cloneable {
      @Override
      protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
      }    
      //всё остальное
    }
```

Comment: В интерфейсе Cloneable нет никаких методов, он маркерный, и соотвественно утверждение "нужно реализовать его" не верно.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, Более того часто и не нужно выставлять `clone()` на публику. Я нередко использую shallow-copy как внутреннюю низкоуровневую техническую операцию, поэтому пишу `implements Cloneable`, но не переопределяю `clone()`, потому что кому попало давать клонировать не надо.

Comment: @s_klepcha, ответ плюсанул, но не пояснено следующее. Допустим вставил я интерфейс     Cloneable     в код. 
А как в 'main' создать клон? 
Какой примерно командой?
Код     Korobka k4;
           k4 = (Korobka)k1.clone();

Comment: Апдейт. Уже пояснили.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно, чтобы ваш класс `Korobka` имплементил маркерный интерфейс `Cloneable`.

Далее, вам надо переопределить метод `clone()` и сделать его публичным. Тогда вы сможете где угодно в своем коде клонировать коробки.

**P.S.** Прежде чем переопределять метод, почитайте про **глубокое копирование объектов в Java**. Хотя оно тут не пригодится, но всё равно почитайте.